# How to make a floating chat head similar to the one in Facebook messenger in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I've been searching for ways to make a floating chat head like the ones used in Facebook messenger. It needs to be draggable and be visible when the app is minimized, like so :
[image: floating chat head]

But it seems like the only way to do that is to write a wrapper plugin over an existing android library. Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Writing Native Code (in JavaScript/TypeScript) is going to be the only way to accomplish this. This [tutorial](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/create-chat-heads-like-facebook-messenger-32f7f1a62064) on how to do it in Java seems rather straightforward and this can be re-created in NativeScript. You may not have to wrap an existing library. However depending on the library API's that may be a more straightforward route.